# I can't resolve the issue. TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str and work with iapws.iapws97

Tags: python, pandas

I solve gears in machine learning, aimed at the task of data processing. I have a dataset that contains 300,000 rows. It is necessary to carry out data preprocessing related to summation, averaging, etc. This part resolved quickly. Encountered a problem with the library iapws.iapws97 You need to find the enthalpy using this library. https://iapws.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iapws.iapws97.html#iapws.iapws97._Region2 An example from the documentation is given as follows:

I'm using this option:

```
df['IO'] = (df['T_PO'],df['D_PO'])['h']
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

My convolutions are already drying up, I can not solve this problem

UPD: having understood a little understood that the problem is connected with tuples.

All code related to this library:

```
pip install iapws
from iapws.iapws97 import _Region2
df['IO'] = 0 #It doesn't matter here if I create a separate column, here for
             #understanding that it is filled
df['IO'] = _Region2(df['T_PO'],df['D_PO'])['h']
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

In general, the main question now is how to take the data from the column, process it according to this formula, and put the volume back into the column.

Comment: The last one is from the ['h'] after the tuple. It is not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: As far as I understand, this is part of the formula ttps://iapws.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iapws.iapws97.html#iapws.iapws97._Region2

Comment: I can't see the exact bit of the linked document you are trying to copy, but they seem to be calling a function with two parameters whose result is a dict type object. You are missing the function name and the parentheses and parameters of the function are forming a tuple.

Comment: The document link refers to the _Region function. Is that what you meant to invoke? i.e., df['IO'] = _Region(df['T_PO'],df['D_PO'])['h']

Comment: Yes, that's right, I've changed the question.